# elsarticle class: how to get coloured links without boxes?

Tags: hyperref, links, elsarticle

I'm using the `elsearticle` class. At present the links (citations, equation references, etc) are put in coloured boxes and I'd rather have the links coloured without boxes. So I tried putting

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperref]{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = red, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = red, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor   = red %Colour of citations
}
```

But this doesn't work, it turns the boxes off but turns the colour of all the links to blue. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The class does

```
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}
  {\def\@linkcolor{blue}
   \def\@anchorcolor{blue}
   \def\@citecolor{blue}
   \def\@filecolor{blue}
   \def\@urlcolor{blue}
   \def\@menucolor{blue}
   \def\@pagecolor{blue}
\begingroup
  \@makeother\`%
  \@makeother\=%
  \edef\x{%
    \edef\noexpand\x{%
      \endgroup
      \noexpand\toks@{%
        \catcode 96=\noexpand\the\catcode`\noexpand\`\relax
        \catcode 61=\noexpand\the\catcode`\noexpand\=\relax
      }%
    }%
    \noexpand\x
  }%
\x
\@makeother\`
\@makeother\=
}{}}
```

so you need to override this:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperref]{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}
  {\def\@linkcolor{red}
   \def\@anchorcolor{red}
   \def\@citecolor{red}
   \def\@filecolor{red}
   \def\@urlcolor{red}
   \def\@menucolor{red}
   \def\@pagecolor{red}
\begingroup
  \@makeother\`%
  \@makeother\=%
  \edef\x{%
    \edef\noexpand\x{%
      \endgroup
      \noexpand\toks@{%
        \catcode 96=\noexpand\the\catcode`\noexpand\`\relax
        \catcode 61=\noexpand\the\catcode`\noexpand\=\relax
      }%
    }%
    \noexpand\x
  }%
\x
\@makeother\`
\@makeother\=
}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test section}
\href{www.tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX.sx} \cite{test}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{test} Author, Title, 2015
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Or shorter, doing `colorlinks=true` in the preamble and the change for colors

```
\hypersetup{
  linkcolor=red,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=red
}
```

in the body of the document:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperref]{xcolor}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
}

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{
  linkcolor=red,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=red
}
\tableofcontents

\section{Test section}
\href{www.tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX.sx} \cite{test}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{test} Author, Title, 2015
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The result, showing red colorized links:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why they designed it like that?

Comment: @C_Al Most probably they wanted to enforce the blue color as an editorial decision.